# Connection during MySQL import

Tags: mysql, import, ssh, connection

**What happens to a long lasting query executed from commandline via SSH if the connection to MySQL or SSH is lost?**

Context:
We have 2 servers with a very large MySQL database on them.  One server acts as the Master, and the other as Slave.  During regular maintenance, the replication became corrupt, and we noticed data was missing from the slave, even though it reported Seconds_Behind_Master = 0.

So I am in the process of repairing the replication.  I am, as we speak, importing one of two large dumps in to the slave.  I am connected to MySQL through SSH, and used the MySQL "\. file.sql" command to import the dump.

Right now I am constantly getting results like so "Query OK, 6798 rows affected".

**It has been running for probably 30 minutes now.  My question and worry is, what happens if I lose connection through SSH while this is running?**

I have another, even larger dump to import after this.

Thanks for the answer!

-Steve

Comment: just run it as a background process with a & at the end of the command

Answer (score 0):

if you lose your connection, all children of your bash process will die, including mysql.

to avoid this problem use the [screen](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-use-screen-command-under-linux.html) command.

Comment: So are you saying it is too late for my current import?  If I do a show processlist, I can see the thread that is running the import.  Is there anyway to send this to mysql background, leaving it unattended?  My problem right now is that i did the import from within mysql, instead of in linux using mysqlimport.